# Mileage as unit-agnostic term

Tags: measuring-units, cultural-phrases, localization

Is it appropriate to use the term **"mileage"** to **refer to distance that is not measured in the literal units of miles?**  For example, would you say that a car "has a lot of mileage on it" in a country that measures distance in kilometers?  Is there a more unit-neutral term that is better to use universally?

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't matter where there's no potential conflict of registers. We had trouble (when teaching maths) deciding what to call the erstwhile 'mileage charts' when using kilometres, though. (We opted for 'distance charts'.)

Comment: In the US, when we ask about "miles per gallon" fuel efficiency, we may call it *mileage*. http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ In the UK or NZ, etc., when they ask about "liters per kilometer" I assume they do not call it *mileage*, though?

Comment: Note also that the measurement-system-agnostic usage (a 'mileage chart' showing distances in kilometres) is not the same as the metaphorical usage ('there's a lot of mileage left in this suit').

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mileage can certainly be used without having to be associated with literal miles.

[Freedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mileage) defines it as an informal noun, meaning usefulness, or how much service something has provided, or may provide.

[Cambridge dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/mileage) defines it as an advantage that can be obtained from a situation

A person may get good mileage out of a situation, meaning that they made good use of, or made good benefit from a situation. My very old clothes dryer is over 15 years old, and although it now needs replacing, I would say I got excellent mileage from it.

In Australia (where we use kilometres) the term mileage is also used to describe the fuel consumption of a vehicle - I get better mileage from my 2.0 L diesel sedan than my 4.2L V8 street racer. It would still be acceptable to refer to a vehicle having low mileage, although in print (car ads) it is more often described as *low kms* or *low ks*.

Comment: +1 Interesting to think that one day, the average person may not really understand where words come from or why they're the way they are. You lose context. Of course, I suppose it's no different for us. How many people have ever used a telephone with a dial, for instance?

Comment: @Patrick87 FCC rules still require phone companies to accept pulse dialing (like you get from a rotary phone), so my antiques still work just fine. On the other hand there is a reason the brits spell color with a u, but aside from knowing that it makes tracing the origin easier that is one I have no clue about.

Comment: That's the story of etymology in a nutshell, @Patrick87. :) Phone with a dial? You made me feel so old! LOL!

Comment: @Patrick87 How many of us, for that matter, knew where *mile* came from, let alone *mileage*?

Answer (score 4):

Though derived from *mile* the unit of distance, *mileage* as an informal term has a broader sense meaning distance-covered-for-the-fuel-used, a sort of return-on-investment.

*Mile* really is about 'thousands' (in the context of distance); not '1,760 yards' as in use today in formal writing.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mile):

> Old English *mil*, from West Germanic **milja* (cf. Middle Dutch *mile*, Dutch *mijl*, Old High German *mila*, German *meile*), from Latin *mila* "thousands," plural of *mille* "a thousand" (neuter plural was mistaken in Germanic as a fem. singular), of unknown origin.

In informal usage, *mile* does not even reference a fixed distance, implying instead, 'a very long way or a very great amount' ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mile)).

Of course, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I believe *mile* derives from [**mille passi**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile#Roman_mile) a thousand paces.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are right, though *derive* is not exactly the word -- it's shortening, as sometime happens, losing significant meaning in the process.

Comment: @Kris So a mile is shorter than it used to be? I get the impression they're getting longer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Should be. I don't know how a *pace* of those times compares to our 'pace' today, could have been longer :)

Comment: Is that a miley-face?